# How can I get moment.js to treat the date '1234 56 78' as an invalid date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have a Javascript/NodeJS unit test that is trying to verify that an invalid date throws an exception.  The code is like this:

```
let inputDate = '1234 56 78';
let useFormat = 'DD MMM YYYY';
try {
    let aDate = moment(inputDate, useFormat);
    if (isNaN(aDate)){
        throw Error("Invalid date: " + inputDate)
    }
    console.log('date [' + inputDate + '] is valid and parses to [' + aDate.format(useFormat) + ']');

} catch (ex) {
    // success
    console.log('got ex',ex.toString())
}
```

The console output is:

```
date [1234 56 78] is valid and parses to 12 Jan 1978
```

You can run this in jsbin.com easily to reproduce the error, sorry I don't have a link to it.

**What do I need to do in order to get moment to treat this as an invalid date?**

Or perhaps, what do **I need to learn** to understand that the date is valid. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Running Moment.js in [strict mode](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/)** will reject the input:

```
let aDate = moment(inputDate, useFormat, true);
```